# What is more beneficial continue with the voluntary AOW pension scheme in the Netherlands or invest in a local (Belgian) commercial pension fund?

Tags: netherlands, pension, belgium

This year I have quitted my job in the Netherlands. Since I have been living in Belgium for almost a decade, I will start loosing 2% per year from the final AOW pension. I can [voluntarily continue paying the AOW pension fees](https://www.svb.nl/int/en/vv/wonen_werken_buiten_nederland/buiten_nl_wonen_werken/index.jsp), the fees however are quit hefty (17% of your annual income, with a maximum of [5.067,00](https://www.svb.nl/int/en/vv/wonen_werken_buiten_nederland/wat_kost_de_vv/index.jsp)

I am consulting various commercial providers, but I was wondering if you could assume that continuing the Dutch AOW pension scheme is by all means worth investing in, if you have have already been paying AOW fees while living and working in the Netherlands.

Comment: Half of this looks like a not-too-difficult spreadsheet calculation to me. Fill in the Dutch numbers in a spreadsheet and calculate costs (up until your pension age) and benefits (starting from there). The other half (Belgian commercial fund) is going to be much more speculative, I doubt that anyone can give a good answer there.